# Jade Display Nested Value without ID

Tags: json, node.js, nested, pug

I am finding it difficult to display a certain part of my JSON output as it has not "title" if that is what it is called.

```
{ name: 'john',
  display: 'John Doe',
  abr: 'JD',
  balance: 1.0,
  address:
   { 'address1': 1.0,
     'address2': 0.08,
     'address3': 0,
     'address4': 0 } }
```

In Jade i can do `each address in user.address` and then display using `#{address}` but this only shows the numeric value at the end, how can i display both the address and the value as separate values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is overload of the `each` where you can get the index (in this case the name of the properties) as the second argument:

```
each addressValue, addressName in user.address
    p address name: #{addressName} value: #{addressValue}
```

And the generated HTML will look like:

```
<p>address name: address1 value: 1</p>
<p>address name: address2 value: 0.08</p>
```